# Javascript Quandary: Creating a highlighter pen tool... almost there

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, highlight

I'm working on a little JS plugin that I want to function exactly like a real highlighter pen. Take a standard div of html text (with children), select text with mouse, and leave the highlighting intact on mouse up. Seems fairly straight forward, right?

Here is what I have so far: http://efflux.us/text/views/select.php
(the window on the right just outputs your selection for testing purposes)

So if you select a few words of text, everything works fine. Try selecting a few groups of words, and you'll notice the css background changes. However, I have two glaring issues...

1) Selecting multiple lines of text does not work. When selecting multiple lines, the getSelection() function does not grab the `<br />` tags.. which are needed to match up the string inside the main container `<div class='text>`. These `<br />` tags are crucial to the app I'm building, so they are definitely needed. When removing them, multiple lines can be selected.

2) When selecting a common word or phrase, every instance of it gets highlighted. I would like just the selected text to be highlighted, but can't figure it out. Try selecting the very first word "The"... you'll see what happens.

Side notes..
I'm basing the highlighting functionality off Johann Burkard's highlight plugin.. but can't think of any way to further modify the script. I'm willing to write something fresh, but have been racking my brain to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Have you seen [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/). This does everything you want, but cleaner. It runs on HTML5's canvas element, so it won't work on older browsers, but it solves the problem at hand.

Comment: @tjameson: How is Ace relevant here?

Comment: @tjameson: Actually, Ace doesn't use a canvas element for editing.

Comment: @Tim- Really? I thought it came from Bespin, which used Canvas. It already has the editor built-in, with highlighting already a feature. It doesn't have to be recreated and it's supported by Mozilla, so it's probably not going to be very buggy. And it's easy to change the cursor to a highlighter pen.

Comment: @tjameson: Bespin did indeed use canvas and became Skywriter then I think merged with a separate thing called Ace. Whatever, it certainly doesn't use canvas now. Doing so in the first place always looked like insanity to me (it chucks away and reimplements all the masses of text editing functions browsers give you for free), and it seems the authors came to the same conclusion. The HTML5 canvas spec even has a long section attempting to dissuade authors from writing a text editor using canvas: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#best-practices

Comment: @tjameson: The reason I didn't think Ace was relevant is that it's specifically a code editor and dissimilar to the content the OP linked to (being an editor and using monospaced fonts being two immediate issues that spring to mind).

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this is reasonably straightforward using `document.execCommand()`. It's slightly complicated by the fact that you need to temporarily make the document editable in non-IE browser for `document.execCommand()` to work, which in turn destroys the selection in some browsers, but that's easy enough to work around. It works in all major browsers, including IE 6.

**UPDATE: Fixed for IE 9.**

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/Hp7Zs/32/

Code:

```
function makeEditableAndHighlight(colour) {
    var range, sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";
    if (range) {
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
    // Use HiliteColor since some browsers apply BackColor to the whole block
    if (!document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, colour)) {
        document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
}

function highlightSelection(colour) {
    var range, sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        try {
            if (!document.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour)) {
                makeEditableAndHighlight(colour);
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            makeEditableAndHighlight(colour)
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        // IE <= 8 case
        range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.execCommand("BackColor", false, colour);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, Tim.. you're the man! I'll play around with your script and get back to you.