# Semantics of clientRect from getClientRects in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, selection, range

In webkit browsers (this does not seem to be an issue in IE9 or Mozilla) when one queries the range for the clientRects (getClientRects), the returned clientrects contain the rectangles of text that correspond to the selected text, but also clientrects of the start of any element within the range. How can I determine which clientrects belong to the elements.

For instance lets say this para was rendered with the same line breaks i have here:

```
<p>This is some text StartSelection in a paragraph 
    blah blah<span>this is some EndOfSelection blah
    more text</span>
</p>
```

If I selected from StartSelection to EndOfSelection and then queried the range from the selection - getRangeAt(0)

I would get back this array of clientRects:

```
0. rect of 'StartSelection in a paragraph'
1. rect of 'blah blah'
2. rect of 'this is some EndOfSelection blah'
3. rect of 'more text'
4. rect of 'this is some EndOfSelection'
```

The only rects I want are 0, 1, & 4. Rects 2 & 3 represent the contents of the  start tag of elements that the selection crosses.

Geometric inspection of the rects would allow me to discard 2 & 3, but the code strikes me as a bit brittle, especially if my selection were to extend to the third line. Is there anyway to determine the source of the rects without geometric inspection, which i can use to discard 2 & 3?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve with `getClientRects()`?

Comment: I am trying to highlight text, separate from text selection. If I could pump multiple ranges into the selection i could live with that, but that appears to have limited support.

Comment: Why not walk the Range's DOM or use `document.execCommand()` (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972581/javascript-quandary-creating-a-highlighter-pen-tool-almost-there/6972694#6972694)?

Comment: Thanks I had not seen that answer, nice elegant solution, however I do not want to alter the content for other reasons. So I am going route of separate planes/decorations (over, under) with rects to indicate highlights.

Comment: Hmm. I see the problem. I'd submit a bug to WebKit and try and find a workaround.

Comment: @Tim To implement my highlighting scheme completely I need to understand whether to place the decoration above or below the element (background-color et al). The ideal solution would be to query the dom for all elements that contain an x/y position, preferably ordered by zindex. This is simple with block/div elements, though seems a bit more problematic for spans. Any ideas/pointers?

Comment: You still need to get accurate rects for the range text. I've done something similar to what you're trying to do before but only in a situation where every word is contained within its own `<span>`. I'm a bit stumped. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I'm aware. This feature of `Range` is relatively new in all browsers, I've seen very little written about it so I assume it's not widely used and there may well be browser bugs. This, for example, seems like a WebKit bug, because it seems to me on a quick reading to violate [the part of the CSSOM View spec pertaining to Ranges](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-range-interface).